# Centering slide window in keynote

Tags: keynote

I'm editing a keynote and i would like to center the slide I am editing in the middle of the window, simply for editing. It seems to stick to the top left corner of the window. How do i centralize the slide I am editing (only for editing purposes) in the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the editable slide in the main pane of the Keynote window, right?

I do not believe you can change where it displays in the window. Your best bet may be to resize the window such that the slide appears to be centered (i.e. use the smallest window size that fits the slide), then put the window in the middle of the screen.